# How to make a chart with SVG marker whose size increases in only one aspect or show a custom SVG marker for each data point in Vega/Vega-Lite?

Tags: svg, data-visualization, vega-lite, vega

I want to make a chart that has "spikes" as markers. And to denote the "severity" or the "quantitative" nature of the data, I want to scale the "spikes" longer but NOT wider. Currently, when I use the `size` encoding it increases the **area** of the "spike", which is undesirable. I used `"aspect": false` too but the results did not change -

**Vega-Lite Spec**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 28}, {"a": "B", "b": 55}, {"a": "C", "b": 43},
      {"a": "D", "b": 91}, {"a": "E", "b": 81}, {"a": "F", "b": 53},
      {"a": "G", "b": 19}, {"a": "H", "b": 87}, {"a": "I", "b": 52}
    ]
  },
  "mark": {"type": "point", "shape":"M -1 0 L0 -10 L1 0", "fill": "red", "opacity": 0.5, "stroke": "black", "strokeOpacity": 1 },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "ordinal"},
    "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"},
    "size": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

[image]

Then I thought that maybe I can specify `shape` as an encoding and provide custom SVG that only changes in height, as PATH value to the data itself and pass that in the shape encoding. But of course that didn't work. Vega-Lite assigned its own shapes -

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 28, "c":"M -1 0 L0 -10 L1 0"}, {"a": "B", "b": 55, "c":"M -1 0 L0 -5 L1 0"}, {"a": "C", "b": 43, "c":"M -1 0 L0 -20 L1 0"},
      {"a": "D", "b": 91, "c":"M -1 0 L0 -1 L1 0"}
    ]
  },
  "mark": {"type": "point", "fill": "red", "opacity": 0.5, "stroke": "black", "strokeOpacity": 1 },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "ordinal"},
    "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"},
    "shape": {"field": "c", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

[image]

I also played around with `url` encoding in `point` mark as well as `image` mark, but they did not yield anything.

I saw [Path Mark](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/marks/path/) in Vega, which may be useful but I do not see it in Vega-Lite. If it can somehow be used then that is fine too.

Any idea how do I make this happen?

Main idea is to have the width of the marker same, but scale the height. I don't mind doing it via encoding channels or arguments/parameters or specifying an SVG PATH for each data point, either way is fine.

### **EDIT 1**

After fiddling with vega, I got around to the following -

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "background": "white",
  "padding": 5,
  "height": 700,
  "style": "cell",
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "source_0",
      "values": [
        {"a": "A", "b": 1.5, "c": 0},
        {"a": "B", "b": 0.5, "c": 0},
        {"a": "C", "b": 10, "c": 0},
        {"a": "D", "b": 1, "c": 0}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "data_0",
      "source": "source_0",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "filter",
          "expr": "isValid(datum[\"b\"]) && isFinite(+datum[\"b\"])"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "signals": [
    {"name": "x_step", "value": 20},
    {
      "name": "width",
      "update": "bandspace(domain('x').length, 1, 0.5) * x_step"
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "marks",
      "type": "symbol",
      "style": ["path"],
      "from": {"data": "data_0"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "opacity": {"value": 0.7},
          "fill": {"value": "red"},
          "stroke": {"value": "red"},
          "strokeOpacity": {"value": 1},
          "strokeWidth": {"value": 0.25},
          "shape": {"value": "M -1 0 L0 -10 L1 0 Z"},
          "ariaRoleDescription": {"value": "point"},
          "description": {
            "signal": "\"a\" + \": \" + (isValid(datum[\"a\"]) ? datum[\"a\"] : \"\"+datum[\"a\"]) + \"; \" + \"b\" + \": \" + (format(datum[\"b\"], \"\"))"
          },
          "x": {"scale": "x", "field": "a"},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "c"},
          "scaleY": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "point",
      "domain": {"data": "data_0", "field": "a", "sort": true},
      "range": {"step": {"signal": "x_step"}},
      "padding": 0.5
    },
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "linear",
      "domain": {"data": "data_0", "field": "b"},
      "range": [{"signal": "height"}, 0],
      "nice": true,
      "zero": true
    },
    {
      "name": "size",
      "type": "linear",
      "domain": {"data": "data_0", "field": "b"},
      "range": [0, 361],
      "zero": true
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {
      "scale": "y",
      "orient": "left",
      "gridScale": "x",
      "grid": true,
      "tickCount": {"signal": "ceil(height/40)"},
      "domain": false,
      "labels": false,
      "aria": false,
      "maxExtent": 0,
      "minExtent": 0,
      "ticks": false,
      "zindex": 0
    },
    {
      "scale": "x",
      "orient": "bottom",
      "grid": false,
      "title": "a",
      "labelAlign": "right",
      "labelAngle": 270,
      "labelBaseline": "middle",
      "labelOverlap": true,
      "zindex": 0
    },
    {
      "scale": "y",
      "orient": "left",
      "grid": false,
      "title": "b",
      "labelOverlap": true,
      "tickCount": {"signal": "ceil(height/40)"},
      "zindex": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Which gives me -
[image]

I tried to convert this to Vega-Lite but it doesn't seem to work -

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 2}, {"a": "B", "b": 5}, {"a": "C", "b": 4},
      {"a": "D", "b": 9}
    ]
  },
  "mark": {"type": "point", "shape":"M -1 0 L0 -10 L1 0", "fill": "red", "opacity": 0.5, "stroke": "black", "strokeOpacity": 1 },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "ordinal", "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}},
    "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"},
    "scaleY": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

**Error**

```
Property scaleY is not allowed.
```

Answer (score 3):

Your second approach, of providing the SVG path in the `shape` encoding, will work if you set the `scale` to `null` ([open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABBBoIcguIaZJ1h2DcyGA7nRiHETOMtXLDypJhUiioBKKigxEiCDGpoANqgYSD6wUxoAEwAHEpQaCAAsob8AIyGAAyGADIVJRWVpWUgAL4KiXkAQqloAKzdOXmFJeVVNd1VDc2tIEkAwl2oYgDM-eiDDSNF6XUTLW3oACLzAJzFKwVF69UX4+XNALotIMjqANZooJgAnjhweThsNFkmGCADMaIJBHl1F5gmwcEgoHRPmgypQ+iAIJh1GwXr90ExBAi3kpMdjcQB5eGIr5oYqPOCyKBsZSAsjvEAAD3ZYLggmUeRQSi+PzybHULNkUUmIGR4RAPL5eTSQu+eJAAEcGEggXQAjRSNKIDAkCK5Qr+ehcirTRqtTrAjoDSSoFE8bIGBCml6gA)):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 28, "c":"M -1 0 L0 -10 L1 0"},
      {"a": "B", "b": 55, "c":"M -1 0 L0 -5 L1 0"},
      {"a": "C", "b": 43, "c":"M -1 0 L0 -20 L1 0"},
      {"a": "D", "b": 91, "c":"M -1 0 L0 -1 L1 0"}
    ]
  },
  "mark": {"type": "point", "fill": "red", "opacity": 0.5, "stroke": "black", "strokeOpacity": 1 },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "ordinal"},
    "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"},
    "shape": {"field": "c", "type": "quantitative", "scale": null}
  }
}
```

[image]

Vega-Lite does not provide the equivalent of Vega's `ScaleY` encoding, so if you want that approach you will have to work in Vega directly.

Comment: For the moment I can accept it, no worries. But I am wondering how did you find out that setting the `scale` to `null` would solve the issue. I think I went through the docs, couldn't find anything regarding that. Is it mentioned anywhere?

Comment: Disabling scales is covered briefly here: https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/scale.html#disable